# MySQL double query in single query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, multiple-tables

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE folders (
ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
uid BIGINT NOT NULL,
driveid BIGINT NOT NULL,
foldername VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
icon_url varchar(260),
time_created timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
time_updated timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
time_expires timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE drives (
ID BIGINT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
uid BIGINT NOT NULL,
drivename VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
icon_url varchar(260),
time_created timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
time_updated timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00' on update CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
time_expires timestamp NOT NULL default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to select drives and all folders where:

1. in drives table where `uid = UID NUMBER`
2. in folders, where `dbid = ID` from drives which also does have `UID = given UID number`

I want to a single query and get entire result in a single response. Is it possible?
If so please advice, I don't want to paste what I tried as they are stupid, I tried inner join, left join, mixed queries, but I didn't get close.

Comment: So your relationship is `drives.ID = folders.dbid`? And the `uid` number you want to filter for -- is that the _same_ uid for both `drives` and `folders`, or is it a _different_ uid?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, yes, it's same UID, in fact it should be same UID, UID is for user ID, DBID for drive ID

Comment: `driveid` is `NOT NULL`, so every folder belongs to one drive, but are there drives which have no folders for a `uid`, and should they be returned?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski imagine it exactly like a computer file system, there is folders which is created under specific drives, user can have unlimited drives and each drive will have unlimited folder. So all folders in folders table, will have UID and DRIVEID, UID => user ID and DriveID => for ID in drives table. UID for specific user is same in folders table and drives table.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski, for this specific issue, I'm open to all type of ideas for specially performance and quality issues, even if you tell me a better design for tables, I'm OK to redesign it all. There drives, folders and then files table.

Comment: I think the design is fine, and I believe my answer should cover it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, this amounts to a `LEFT JOIN` with two conditions. If the `uid` has records in `drives` with no associated folders, the drive will be returned along with `NULL`s in the folder columns.  The `driveid` must match `drives.ID`, and the `uid` must be the same; both of these will be specified in the `ON` clause.

```
SELECT
  drives.ID AS driveid,
  drives.drivename,
  drives.uid,
  folders.ID AS folderid,
  folders.foldername,
  folders.icon_url,
  drives.time_created AS drive_time_created,
  drives.time_updated AS drive_time_updated,
  drives.time_expires AS drive_time_expires,
  folders.time_created AS folders_time_created,
  folders.time_updated AS folders_time_updated,
  folders.time_expires AS folders_time_expires
FROM
  drives
  LEFT JOIN folders
    ON drives.ID = folders.driveid
    AND drives.uid = folders.uid
WHERE
  drives.uid = [the-specified-uid]
```

Comment: Folder without drive is impossible, drive without folder is possible. So still you think this answer should work well?

Comment: Yes - that's what this left join targets - it's possible to return drives without folders.

Comment: Thank you, I'll try it and let you know results.

Comment: Do you think my design is good performance-wise for drives and folders ? Any suggestions/ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you need a `union` query for this.  I'm not exactly sure what the query is, because your question doesn't specify sample data or desired results.  For instance, it is unclear which user id you want for the comparison.

However, the following should be pretty close to what you want:

```
select d.id as driveid, NULL as folderid
from drives d
where d.uid = @UID
union all
select d.id, f.id as folderid
from drives d join
     folders f
     on f.dbid = d.id
where f.uid = @UID;
```

Comment: I want same user ID, so basically there is user drives and folders. So I want to read all drives and folders for specific UID, folders.dbid ==> drives.id